# Show all modules used in a page

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

Is it is possible to check all the modules used for a particular page in magento2?

Comment: Needs details or clarity

Answer (score 3):

You can add below line in your htaccess which will give you an approx idea about modules or stack trace on that page.

```
SetEnv MAGE_PROFILER "html"
```

Flush your cache and refresh the page, this will be available for every page which you will browse.

[image: luma theme]